# Code refactoring of parameter passed Person Account

Tags: apex

Anyone know a better way to refactor this code so it won't be hardcoded PersonAccount? Instead, it should be parameter passed in?

```
String personAccRecTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('PersonAccount').getRecordTypeId();
```

I have read this blog and with a SOQL query might work but I am still thinking if there is a better approach that won't break?
http://smukov.github.io/blog/2018/06/09/Record-Type-Id-By-Developer-Name/

Comment: You could use custom setting (list) or if there are needs for it to be migrated in package use custom metadata and in your apex change such that first you get the value as recordTypeVar from either Custom setting or Custom Metadata and use it

Answer (score 1):

Might be one of the few times where it's still better to query the `RecordType`, as the `RecordTypeInfo` does not surface `IsPersonType`, which is more programmatic than checking `DeveloperName` (especially since you can in fact have multiple).

```
SELECT DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE IsPersonType = true
```